# Restricting the textboxes in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have three text boxes named as `textbox1`, `textbox2` and `textbox3`. I need a functionality to retrict in the following manner.

1) If I enter a value in `textbox1` the remaining 2 textboxes should not allow to enter value.

2) If I enter a value in `textbox2` the remaining 2 textboxes should not allow to enter value.

3) If I enter a value in `textbox3` the remaining 2 textboxes should not allow to enter value.

Can anyone please help me out from this. Thanks in advance. As I am new to angularjs. I tried with this code but the first condition itself not working.

Here it is my HTML and JS:

```js
var timesPerWeek = $scope.times[index];
var timesPerMonth = $scope.month[index];
var timesPerYear =  $scope.year[index];

if(timesPerWeek != ""){
  timesPerMonth.disabled =  'true';
  timesPerYear.disabled =  'true';
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2" style="margin-left: -14px;">
     <input type="number" class="form-data" ng-disabled="!check[item.sid]"      id="timesperweek{{item.sid}}" ng-model="times[item.sid]" ng-       change="getValues(item.sid)">
</div>
 
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2" style="margin-left: -13px;">
    <input type="number" class="form-data" ng-disabled="!check[item.sid]" id="timespermonth{{item.sid}}" ng-model="month[item.sid]">
</div>

<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="margin-left: -14px;">
     <input type="number" class="form-data" ng-disabled="!check[item.sid]"      id="timesperyear{{item.sid}}" ng-model="year[item.sid]">
</div>
```

Comment: please provide the fiddle with the scenario.

Comment: I have edited my question with code which I tried. Please check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have three text boxes named as textbox1, textbox2 and textbox3. I need a functionality to retrict in the following manner.

I do not know your how works your code now (you showed us almost nothing in the question).

So the easiest way to disable two other elements just to check in `ng-disabled` if values are not undefined:

```
<div>
     <input type="number" ng-disabled="month[item.sid] != undefined || year[item.sid] != undefined" id="timesperweek{{item.sid}}" ng-model="times[item.sid]">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="number" ng-disabled="times[item.sid] != undefined || year[item.sid] != undefined" id="timespermonth{{item.sid}}" ng-model="month[item.sid]">
</div>

<div>
     <input type="number" ng-disabled="times[item.sid] != undefined || month[item.sid] != undefined" id="timesperyear{{item.sid}}" ng-model="year[item.sid]">
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jp0ybdm2/)

Comment: This is what I need, working perfectly. Thanks a lot friend.